# python lists, regular expressions?

Tags: python, list

Learning Python. I would like to check if list items of lines in 'file1', **at specific indeces**, match list items of lines in file2 at the same indices.

e.g if list items of a line in 'file1' have [t, a, b, c, f], how do I check for lines in file2, that have 'b' on index [2] **and** 'f' on index [3]  such as [p, x, b, l, f].
the code should then loop searching for the matching lines.

Comment: What attempt have you made so far?

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning for 'f' on index 3? In both arrays you have shown `f` is at index 4?

Comment: I guess he meant 4

Comment: Thank you for the guide. Yes i meant '4' for  index occupied by 'f'. This is what i ahve attempted                                                                          file_1 = ['t', 'b', 'a', 'y', 'f']
file_2 = ['p', 'x', 'b', 'y', 'f']i = 0
while i < len(file_1):    if file_1[i] == file_2[i]:
print('Match Found, file_1 and file_2 have the letter {} in common at index {}'.format(file_1[i], i))    i += 1

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `zip()` :

```
>>> file1 = ['t', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f']
>>> file2 = ['p', 'x', 'b', 'l', 'f']
>>> [k==v for k, v in zip(file1, file2)]
[False, False, True, False, True]
```

Or by using `enumerate` :

```
>>> [file1[index] == file2[index] for index, data in enumerate(file1)]
[False, False, True, False, True]
```

This is just the illustration of comparing list, you can iterate your file lines accoedingly

Comment: `True if ... == ... else False` is rather superfluous. Just `... == ..,` will do exactly the same.

Comment: OP said samething about regular expressions, so it's probably more like `[re.matches(k, v) for ...]` but the idea is the same.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I have shorten my code, pls check and let me know